# Product attribute value visible in Catalog table but its field is empty in Edit Product form

Tags: attributes, catalog, magento-2.2.5

I have a strange issue with Magento 2.2.5 where two of my product attributes have its values showing in the Catalog Table, but when you click into the product itself to edit, the field for that attribute is empty.

Catalog table:
[image]

Product edit form:
[image]

I've tried a full reindex, and cleared the Magento cache as well, but none of that helps.

I've compared the two attribute configurations on a database level using:

```
SELECT * FROM `mydb`.`eav_attribute` WHERE `backend_type` = "varchar"
```

But the configurations are exactly the same as other attributes where it doesn't have such an issue.

I have also compared the actual value in database with other attributes that don't have this issue:

```
SELECT * FROM `catalog_product_entity_varchar`
```

Again, exactly the same.

Interesting note, when I duplicate the product, the two attributes are the **only fields that do not get cloned over** to the duplicate product. This means that the duplicate product has these two fields set to the field's default values, and even these default values don't appear in the Edit Product form!
I have no idea what else I can try to fix this.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Checking the system log, I was hitting into this error:

```
[2019-05-27 04:12:12] main.WARNING: Attempt to load value of nonexistent EAV attribute '180' 
                        for entity type 'Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface'. [] []
```

Google-d this error and a whole bunch of unsolved problems showed up. It seems that many users are hitting into this error after migrating from Magento 1 to 2, but this was not my use case.

Then I stumbled upon this answer: [Magento 2.2.4 adding new custom attribute error "Attempt to load value of nonexistent EAV attribute"](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/236251/magento-2-2-4-adding-new-custom-attribute-error-attempt-to-load-value-of-nonexi)

So apparently I had to run:

```
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Clearing the cache from the admin UI was not enough. I'm not exactly sure what's the difference between running this command and clearing the cache from the UI, but that did the trick and solved my issue. I am now able to see the attributes in product edit screen, and able to change and save the attribute values without issues.